# understanding the term 落ち着いた暖色の照明

Tags: usage

> お客様が車内で快適にお過ごしいただけるよう、既存車両よりも広い座席、全席分の電源コンセント、無料公衆無線ＬＡＮ、落ち着いた暖色の照明、新宿駅停車中の車内ＢＧＭなど、さまざまなサービスを提供します。

I understand from the text above about various features inside the train. But this term "落ち着いた暖色の照明", I am not sure what to exactly make out of it. From kanji, I can get to calm and warm lighting or soothing warm lighting at the most. Is there anything I miss?

Comment: What problem do you find with your translation?

Comment: @macraf I am not able to understand how to exactly translate the term. This is the first time I have been in this sort of dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

落ち着いた is modifying 暖色の, and 暖色の is modifying 照明. (Or 落ち着いた may be modifying 暖色の照明 as a whole, but the nuance is essentially the same.)

- 落ち着いた: calm, subdued, soothing
- 暖色: "warm" color (red, orange, yellow, etc) as opposed to white/blueish color. see [this](https://www.webcolordesign.net/color_basic/color_psychology/warm_cold_color.html)

So 落ち着いた暖色の照明 refers to something like this:

[image: 暖色の照明]

Comment: Thank you for the image. I think now I have a good idea for the translation.